# XMLReader : get attributes value from NSDictionary

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios4, xmlreader

I'm using the XMLReader class from http://troybrant.net/blog/,

it parsea an xml into an NSDictionary, for example :

```
NSString *myxml=@"< students od=\"ii\">< student>< name>Raju< /name>< age>25< /age>< address>abcd< /address>< /student>< /students>";
NSDictionary *dict = [XMLReader dictionaryForXMLString:myxml error:nil];
```

gives me an NSDictionary like:

```
students = 
{
    "@od" = ii;
    student = 
    {
        address = abcd;
        age = 25;
        name = Raju;
    };
};
```

I can perfectly extract any of these parameters except for the attributes.  Can someone tell me how to get the value of 'od'?
Thanks.

EDIT :
i resolved th problem,actually i had to create a new NSDictionary :
 NSDictionary *str = [students valueForKey:@"@od"];

Comment: `NSString *str = [students valueForKey:@"\"@od\""];` does not work? Or  `NSString *str = [students valueForKey:@"@od"];`

Comment: i resolved th problem,actually i had to create a new NSDictionary : NSDictionary *str = [students valueForKey:@"@od"];

Comment: Add your own answer and mark this question as answered then please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT : i resolved th problem,actually i had to create a new NSDictionary : 
NSDictionary *str = [students valueForKey:@"@od"];

Answer (score 1):

Why not use `NSXMLParser`?  The delegate method returns an `NSDictionary` full of the attributes in `- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict`